# File Path retrieval from local directory in java

Tags: java, file, path

problem statement: Language used Java, type of files is .feature

1. Scan all files from root folder that are located inside rootdirect folder --> C:/src/test/resources/root
   Note: Root folder has more than 100 files and subfolders
2. Reading all files and matching with some string, if text matches then returning file name
3. Get path of file derived from step 2 &  get the complete line on which text found

I am good with step 1 & 2 but got stuck in step 3. No matter what I used - File.getPath() or File.getAbsolutePath() it is not returning me full path of derived files.

```
public class ABC{

   static String maindirpath = "C:\\Users\\<xxx>\\<somefolder>\\ <src\\test\\resources\\rootdirect";
   static File maindir = new File(maindirpath); 

   String findText1 = "sometext";
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    if(maindir.exists() && maindir.isDirectory()) 
            { 
                // array for files and sub-directories  
                // of directory pointed by maindir 
                File arr[] = maindir.listFiles(); 
    
                // Calling recursive method 
                RecursiveScan(arr,0,0);  
            }  
     }

       void RecursiveScan(File[] arr,int index,int level) throws IOException  
    { 
        
        
        // terminate condition 
        if(index == arr.length)  
        {   String eof = "No file exist";
            usingBufferedWritter(eof);
            return; 
        }
          
        // tabs for internal levels 
        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print("\t");
            String tab = "\t";
            usingBufferedWritter(tab);
            
           
        }
          
        // for files 
        if(arr[index].isFile()) 
        {
            String fileName = arr[index].getName();
            
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner (arr[index]);
           int linenum =1;
            while (myReader.hasNext())
            {
                String data = myReader.nextLine();
                if(data.contains(findText1))
                 {
                    //to print file name
                    System.out.println("Match found on " + arr[index].getName());
                File fpath = new File(fileName);
                String abspath = fpath.getAbsolutePath();
                System.out.println("abs path "+abspath);
                
                String pth = fpath.getPath();
                System.out.println("path "+pth);
                    
                  }
                
                linenum++;
            }
         
        
                
            
            
         }
           
            
          
        // for sub-directories 
        else if(arr[index].isDirectory()) 
        { 
            System.out.println("[" + arr[index].getName() + "]"); 
            
           
            // recursion for sub-directories 
            
            RecursiveScan(arr[index].listFiles(), 0, level + 1); 
        } 
       
        // recursion for main directory 
   
        RecursiveScan(arr,++index, level); 
    }   

}
```

Current output :

1. abs path    C:\Users<xxx>\\filename.feature
2. Path   filename.feature

Expected output:

for files in rootdirec folder
"C:\Users<xxx><somefolder><src\test\resources\rootdirect\filename.feature"

for files in a subdirectory of rootdirect folder
"C:\Users<xxx><somefolder><src\test\resources\rootdirect\subfolder\filename.feature"
OR

<src\test\resources\rootdirect\subfolder\subfolder1\filename.feature"

Comment: Show us what you've tried. Only then we can tell you what you've done incorrectly.

Comment: Providing code snipped and result you get and result you want to achive would help to understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

You already have the File from `if(arr[index].isFile())`:

```
File fpath = arr[index]
```

Comment: The problem here is how to get the full path of the file, not the file name.

Comment: By replacing `File fpath = new File(fileName)` with above,  you are using the File object that you opened in the Scanner, and the very next line of code is: `String abspath = fpath.getAbsolutePath();`

Comment: Thank you so much. it really resolved the issue of getting a full path. Any suggestion around getting the full line on which text matched ?

Comment: It is hard to believe you wrote it and don't have that data at hand!

Comment: Forgot to add - you can add `break` once you have found a match, so you don't scan the whole file.

Comment: I got it, I am new to StackOverflow so didn't figure out how to edit a comment
I didn't add a break because I want all the lines to be in the output file. But thanks for your suggestion.